# Is it possible to enable the MemManage_Handler in a STM32 L0

Tags: arm, interrupt, stm32

I've written a program which triggers the `HardFault_Handler`. I believe it is because of a out of memory exception but I want to be completely sure about it. I've seen people disable [system interrupt handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411824/determining-arm-cortex-m3-ram-size-at-run-time) on M3/M4 cores and the reference datasheet states that

> (19-Feb-2016) **Nested Vector Interrupt Controller**
>
> Removed MemManage_Handler, BusFault_Handler,Usagefault
>   _Handler and DebugMon_Handler from Table 53: List of vectors.
>   Updated EXTI_IMR reset value. (19-Feb-2016)

This means that once upon a time the `MemManage_Handler` existed and that it could be enabled/disabled. But no documentation of this exists. **Is it possible to enable this handler?**

I personally find it hard to believe that ST has completely removed this handler from the silicon and as such a dormant part of a register should be written to to enable this handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See page 2-17/2-18 of [ARM's Cortex-M0+ Devices Generic User Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0662b/DUI0662B_cortex_m0p_r0p1_dgug.pdf#page=29), which shows the exceptions native to the processor. This part doesn't have a MemManage exception and all exceptions handled by the fault handler go through to the `HardFault`.

I suspect that ST's employees made a copy paste error of the vector table at some point from elsewhere, which did have the `MemManage_Handler`. This also explains the note in the datasheet as they fixed a mistake instead of hiding away a feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

According to Section 3.5 in [Managing memory protection unit (MPU) in STM32 MCUs](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/bc/2d/f7/bd/fb/3f/48/47/DM00272912/files/DM00272912.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00272912.pdf) **there is no MemMange Fault for Cortex-M0+ devices, it only can trigger HardFault for MPU error.**

It is not a ST's decision to remove this feature but Cortex-M0+ simply doesn't have MemMange Fault. I think ST made a copy-and-paste mistake in their documentation.

However, I believe you still can catch MPU errors in the HardFault Handler.